# How do Spark RDDs and DataFrames differ in how they load data into memory?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

**RDD's** are useful because they allow users to process data at the "row" level (or json single object, etc.), without having to load all data into memory. The driver figures out how to distribute the distributed data (or pointers to it) into the workers, and each partition happily executes the code, per line / row / object. Then without having to collect the data in the driver, I can save the result of each partition into a separate text file.

**DataFrames**. How does this work? I suspect it is not the same because I can process a month worth of server logs just fine with a small 8 node cluster using RDD's, but as soon as I try to even *load* the distributed data with `sql_context(spark_context).sql.read.json(s3path)` into a DataFrame it spits all sorts of out of memory errors and the job aborts. The data set is *exactly* the same as the one the RDD performs properly, same cluster, same time-period.

Is there a difference in the way RDD's and DataFrames handles memory loading, in a sense that might explain my results? Please help me understand the differences between RDD"s and DataFRames that might be driving these results. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This a point of understanding with that, and I had this problem too few weeks ago. the function that you are loading:

```
sql_context(spark_context).sql.read.json(s3path)
```

This code according to the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.json) if you don't give the schema the spark will go really deep in your json to find the Types to build the RDD. This works like the inferSchema in load CSV of databricks library.

So what I can recommend you to do is:

- Adding the Schema of the Json with the `sql.types`
- Or, as I know that is a really overhead to do this, use [this method](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.SQLContext.jsonRDD) and after this use `toDF()`

Well, this is the possible problem that you are facing. I didn't have the OOM issue, but it was taking minutes to load something that with RDD is really fast.

Comment: Thanks, this is indeed the correct answer: if you don't specify the schema then Spark will load the data to infer it, imposing an extreme memory overhead for big dataframes. Since my schema is a very long and convoluted nested json object, I wrote a function that makes a query for a minimal amount of data, extracts the <schema>, and then I pass it as the second argument like sql_context(spark_context).sql.read.json(s3path, schema=schema). This solved the issue, thanks again.